# Reading Windows events on XP the time is out by 1 hour, reading Vista the time is correct

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

When reading the date and time a Windows event occurred using XP the time is +1 hour out, when using Vista the time is correct. Both machines have .Net 3.5 installed (same version 3.5.30729.01), the time zone is the same and the time correct, both have the Daylight savings checked.

If I run my program on Vista and read the XP event log the time is out by +1 hour (vista events are correct), if I run my program on XP and read the Vista event log the time is correct, if I read the local XP log the time is out by +1 hour.

Is my program to blame? Is it .Net?

I'm using C#.

Comment: Check localization?, using daylight saving? on the XP box.

Comment: Localization is the same on both boxes (I've just double checked). Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Is your XP machine updated? There was an extension to the daylight saving time last year that needed an XP update to be calculated correctly.